# Docusign Connect Java listener deserializing to incorrect object

Tags: java, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have a Java listener for working with Docusign Connect. Checking out the logs for the connect calls I see the XML as I expected with form fields populated. However, for some reason when the object gets deserialized in the form, the data section is null. I think it may be related to the below SO question:

[Why is my WCF web service presenting this object in a different namespace with different field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686436/why-is-my-wcf-web-service-presenting-this-object-in-a-different-namespace-with-d)

I'm using Apache CXF and Maven to download the API objects from

https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl

However, the deserialized object looks to be different from the XML sent from Connect. Has anyone come across this before or have gotten a listener working in Java which can access the forms fields?

Answer (score 0):

I've never built a Java DocuSign Connect listener application, but I have built one with C#, and I did so by starting with the sample code on GitHub. The Java code is here -- https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/tree/master/Java/Connect -- if nothing else, perhaps comparing it with what you've got may help you identify the issue(s). Or, you might choose to start over by using the GitHub sample app as the basis for building your listener app -- the C# listener app was plug-and-play, I'd expect the Java version to be the same.

Comment: Thanks Kim, I actually did start off looking at the DS java example but it's very barebones and doesn't really do much so I ended up writing my own solution. This seems to work in that I receive the XML from DS and am able to pull some stuff out of it. The only issue is that the deserialized object looks different than the object sent from the server - different properties, etc. Again it looks to be a v similar problem to the question I referenced above but I'm using java rather than WCF.